# get media metadata in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, metadata, attachment

I want to get a media(audio/video) metadata like duration and etc, which is added into a wordpress post.
I'v tried this code in the loop

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ){
    $a = wp_get_attachment_id3_keys($attachment->ID );
    $b = wp_read_video_metadata(wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID));
<?php echo $a['genre'];
    echo $b['duration'];
```

but $a echo just "genre" and $b nothing !
could anyone save me from some big trouble?

Comment: Maybe try a `var_dump` for `$a` and `$b`, to check if everything is working as expected.

Comment: thanks Tomas.could you please explain than a bit more? I'm really beginner to PHP !

Comment: Can you post a little more of the code? If the site isn't live and is just a developvment version, add a `var_dump($a)` below the line where `$a` is assigned.

Comment: Ops ! NULL.
`<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ){
$a = wp_get_attachment_id3_keys($attachment->ID );
$b = wp_read_video_metadata(wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID));
<?php echo $a['genre'];
echo $b['duration'];
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

it's whole code about this section.

Comment: If you didn't have any luck, try using the [`get_attached_media`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) function and then iterate the result of that function call with the foreach. Sorry, but I don't have a WP install to test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. you've done your best